# How do you read every line of the output using Perl's OpenSSH

Tags: perl, ssh, openssh

Using Perl's `Net::SSH::Except`, there is a method called `read_line` which allows me to read every line of the output.

I want to use [`Net::OpenSSH`](http://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH) but I can't find anything similar.

How do you write this `SSH::Except` method using `OpenSSH`?

```
$ssh->send("ls\r\n");

while ( defined( $line = $ssh->read_line() ) {
    # do something
}
```

Comment: I think you probably mean [Net::SSH::Expect](http://metacpan.org/module/Net::SSH::Expect)? You must always *copy* your code and data into a question

Comment: Fair point. Was more of a pointer than a solution

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: If you think you have a solution then please post it. Comments are not the place for extracts or recitations. Also, which module are you talking about? As far as I can see there is nothing like that in the [POD for `Net::OpenSSH`](http://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH), and `Net::SSH::Except` doesn't exist

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: Sorry Chris. I messed up my markdown and had to rewrite, so your answer now precedes my question. But what *is* the source of that "cpan page" extract?

Comment: I take your point, in the Net::OpenSSH there is a capture method.

Answer (score 4):

The Net::OpenSSH module provides a capture method which will capture all the output. If called in list context will return the output line by line

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $host = "localhost";
my %opts = (
        user => 'cdoyle',
        password => 'thisisnottherealpassword',
);
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, %opts);
my @output = $ssh->capture('ls -lrta');

my $count=0;
foreach my $line (@output){
        $count++;
        print "line $count $line";
}
```

gives the output

```
line 1 total 28
line 2 -rw-------  1 cdoyle users   73 Jun 11  2015 .Xauthority
line 3 -rw-------  1 cdoyle users  602 Jun 11  2015 .viminfo
line 4 -rw-r--r--  1 cdoyle users   32 Jun 11  2015 .profile
line 5 drwxr-xr-x  2 cdoyle users 4096 Jun 11  2015 .
line 6 -rw-------  1 cdoyle users  682 Aug 20  2015 .sh_history
line 7 drwxr-xr-x 32 root   root  4096 Feb 21 02:33 ..
```